# python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x

i just want to install nes_py and i get the following error message:

```
Collecting nes_py
  Using cached nes_py-8.1.8.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: gym>=0.17.2 in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nes_py) (0.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nes_py) (1.22.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.5.11,>=1.4.0 in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nes_py) (1.5.11)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.48.2 in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nes_py) (4.63.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.2.0 in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes_py) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gym-notices>=0.0.4 in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes_py) (0.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\hb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.48.2->nes_py) (0.4.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: nes_py
  Building wheel for nes_py (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for nes_py (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for nes_py
Failed to build nes_py
Installing collected packages: nes_py, gym_super_mario_bros
  Running setup.py install for nes_py: started
  Running setup.py install for nes_py: finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [129 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py
      copying nes_py\nes_env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py
      copying nes_py\_image_viewer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py
      copying nes_py\_rom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py
      copying nes_py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\app
      copying nes_py\app\cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\app
      copying nes_py\app\play_human.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\app
      copying nes_py\app\play_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\app
      copying nes_py\app\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\app
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\wrappers
      copying nes_py\wrappers\joypad_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\wrappers
      copying nes_py\wrappers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\nes_py\wrappers
      running build_ext
      building 'nes_py.lib_nes_env' extension
...
╰─> nes_py
```

What I have already tried:

- pip install nes-py --no-cache-dir
- pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

My system:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.10.2 64 Bit
- Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 22):

I also had similar problem but after I installed Cmake everything is fine

```
pip install Cmake
```

Comment: This did it for me

Comment: I had to do this and make sure my loaded gcc had version>4.

Comment: Why does Cmake solve the problem? i don't understand, what is it doing?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error trying to run a SikuliX script on a Windows 10 PC. This is how I solved it:

1. Download and run C++ Build Tools: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
2. Open and select tab Individual Components and install MSVC - v140 VS2015 C++ Build Tools (v14.00) and also and Windows 10 SDK, eg 10.0.20348.0
3. Add a new value to the Environment Variable PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
4. Copy the file `rc.exe` & `rcdll.dll` from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.20348.0\x64

to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

5. Now execute the command that previously produces the error:

**python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.**

Comment: Yes, I got past the error in the OP's subject line by downloading the Build Tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and just installing "Desktop development with C++" and "Visual Studio extension development".  


Got past the error that came next with
`mv C:\\Users\\George\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\~klearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll{,.renamed}`
(Later, I restored the filename.)
Finally, I had to restart Jupyter's kernel twice.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install Cmake using following command

```
pip install Cmake
```

This error was raised because some Python packages contain native extensions that need to be compiled and linked to work correctly. These native extensions may be written in C, C++, or other languages, and they may use third-party libraries or frameworks that need to be installed on the system.

In such cases, cmake can be used to configure, build, and package the native extensions for the Python package. The cmake tool helps manage the build process and dependencies, and generates the necessary files for the build system to compile and package the native extensions into a wheel distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was running `pip install` inside a docker container within a virtual environment

It was solved when I stopped using the virtualenv & ran from `python3`

Comment: This solved my problem. For context, our gitlab ci pipeline was not passing due to a failure to install uwsgi. During the process, we were creating a virtualenv and installing the packages. After removing this step, everything worked out.

Answer (score -1):

This error could be caused by the fact that you haven't installed the wheel package. Depending on your system , check out how to install the wheel package in this short, simple and amazing [tutorial](https://exerror.com/error-invalid-command-bdist_wheel/#:%7E:text=Just%20use%20below%20command%20pip,command%20python%20setup.py%20bdist_wheel.&text=invalid%20command%20%27bdist_wheel%27-,To%20Solve%20error%3A%20invalid%20command%20%27bdist_wheel%27%20Error%20You%20just,command%20python%20setup.py%20bdist_wheel.). After install the wheel package, you can install nes by running `pip install nes-py`. Make sure that you install Visual-Studio 17.0 tools so that the nes package can work on windows.

Comment: Version 2015 and 2017 are installed and wheel in version 0.37.1 as well. Where do I put the command: python setup.py bdist_wheel ?

Comment: The tutorial link provided is trying to load a lot of advertisements, may be carefully check before recommending a website.