# MS Visual C++/Anaconda/pip install error: cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, anaconda

I am having trouble installing the SimpleStereo package: https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo

I have tried everything that has previously been suggested on SO regarding similar **cl.exe' failed with exit code 2** errors, including:

- Clean install of VS 2019 and 2022
- Installing VS C++ build tools
- Checked the python version the creator of SimpleStereo used (3.9.2)
- Checked all older versions of python back to start of 2019
- Added the locations of each cl.exe to my PATH
- Added the location of the cl.exe to the System Variables PATH in case it was a permissions issue
- Adding the cl.exe to the Anaconda env Path using [anaconda develop](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html)

Still keep getting the same error everything I try.

I am using an Anaconda virtual environment. What am I missing/else can I try?

```
(SimpleStereo_new) C:\Users\joini>pip3 install simplestereo
Collecting simplestereo
  Using cached SimpleStereo-1.0.1.tar.gz (66 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from simplestereo) (1.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python<=4.5.3,>=4.5 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from simplestereo) (4.5.2.54)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from simplestereo) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from simplestereo) (3.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (9.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (4.37.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\joini\anaconda3\envs\simplestereo_new\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=3->simplestereo) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: simplestereo
  Building wheel for simplestereo (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [166 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\active.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\calibration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\passive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\points.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\rectification.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\unwrapping.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      running build_ext
      building 'simplestereo._passive' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\simplestereo
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\include -IC:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsimplestereo/_passive.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\simplestereo/_passive.obj
      _passive.cpp
      C:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(21): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(22): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(23): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(26): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(26): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(27): warning C4305: '/=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(30): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(30): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(31): warning C4305: '/=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(34): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(34): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(35): warning C4305: '/=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(48): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(48): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(56): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(56): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(60): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(60): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(64): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(64): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
.
.
.
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'break'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): warning C4552: '>=': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(488): error C3863: array type 'float [tot]' is not assignable
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(495): error C2668: 'exp': ambiguous call to overloaded function
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\cmath(360): note: could be 'long double exp(long double) noexcept'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\cmath(104): note: or       'float exp(float) noexcept'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(475): note: or       'double exp(double)'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(495): note: while trying to match the argument list '(float [tot])'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'continue'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): warning C4552: '<': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for simplestereo
  Running setup.py clean for simplestereo
Failed to build simplestereo
Installing collected packages: simplestereo
  Running setup.py install for simplestereo ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for simplestereo did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [168 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\active.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\calibration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\passive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\points.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\rectification.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\unwrapping.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      copying simplestereo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\simplestereo
      running build_ext
      building 'simplestereo._passive' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\simplestereo
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\include -IC:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsimplestereo/_passive.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\simplestereo/_passive.obj
      _passive.cpp
      C:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\SimpleStereo_new\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(21): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(22): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(23): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(26): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(26): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(27): warning C4305: '/=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(30): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(30): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(31): warning C4305: '/=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(34): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(34): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(35): warning C4305: '/=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(48): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(48): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(56): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(56): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(60): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(60): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(64): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
      C:\Users\joini\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9xp986v\simplestereo_da0f90117aeb41118c737614be215223\simplestereo\headers/colorconversion.hpp(64): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'continue'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(67): warning C4552: '<': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(68): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(68): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(68): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(68): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'break'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(68): warning C4552: '>=': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(157): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(157): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(157): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(157): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(157): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'continue'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(157): warning C4552: '<': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(158): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(158): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(158): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(158): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(158): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'break'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(158): warning C4552: '>=': result of expression not used
.
.
.
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(478): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(478): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'continue'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(478): warning C4552: '<': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'break'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(479): warning C4552: '>=': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(488): error C3863: array type 'float [tot]' is not assignable
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(495): error C2668: 'exp': ambiguous call to overloaded function
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\cmath(360): note: could be 'long double exp(long double) noexcept'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\cmath(104): note: or       'float exp(float) noexcept'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(475): note: or       'double exp(double)'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(495): note: while trying to match the argument list '(float [tot])'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'continue'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(522): warning C4552: '<': result of expression not used
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'kk'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      simplestereo/_passive.cpp(523): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> simplestereo

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Did you check your permissions? Sometimes missing permission can occur installing problems.

Comment: I am admin/only user on this computer. Never had any previous permission problems. Wouldn't I get a different error if it was relating to root privileges?

Comment: Hmm, did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470989/python-setup-py-bdist-wheel-did-not-run-successfully

Comment: installing Cmake? Just tried it and get same error :(

Comment: @a11s did you find a solution? I get the same kind of errors for installing a completely different package, the install of which worked in the past but doesn't anymore.

Comment: No, but the author of the code apparently updated the code to fix or workaround the issue for Windows user. It was too late for me though as I had to switch to a different option to produce what I required. 

Feedback here if you discover anything more that could be useful please, in case I go back to it at some point.