# Python on Macbook: failing to install LXML

Tags: python, xsd

I am working with a batch of 100+ XSDs.  They are heavily nested, with one including multiple others, and each of those including multiple others.

I want to create flattened versions of these.  I am restricted to a Macbook currently.  I have done this once in the past on a PC with XMLSpy, and once on a Mac with OxygenXML (but my license has expired & I’d like to avoid paying for another).

I don’t know enough Python to write scripts, but I can usually run them no problem.

I found https://github.com/esunder/xsdflatten:

I try to run in IDLE and get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

In Terminal I entered pip3 install lxml

I get the error:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [184 lines of output]
ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
```

From [python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470989/python-setup-py-bdist-wheel-did-not-run-successfully)

I ran:

```
pip3 install Cmake
```

Successfully installs, but trying to install lxml gets same error.

From https://exerror.com/error-invalid-command-bdist_wheel/

I ran:

```
pip3 install wheel
```

Got response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.37.1)
```

Feel stuck now: any suggestions for how I can get lxml installed?  Or is installing lxml not for a python noob like myself?

Thank you!

Comment: Macbook? What kind of processor?

Comment: 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5

Comment: Installing wheels for noobs usually works fine if there is a prebuilt one, I would hope that https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/lxml/ has a wheel for your mac/intel os and python version. Building the code itself is of course also possible but perhaps requires the right setup for Python/Cython/C/C++ tools. So I would try to look whether there is a prebuilt wheel for your OS and Python version and go with that version when trying to install lxml.