# Errors when trying to install psycopg2 using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I was trying to install psycopg2 using pip when I got the errors:

```
subprocess-exited-with-error and legacy-install-failure
```

The following is the error description:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg
      gcc -pthread -B /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include -I/home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include/python3.9 -I. -I/home/aayush/miniconda3/envs/vunetenv/include -I/home/aayush/miniconda3/envs/vunetenv/include/server -I/home/aayush/miniconda3/envs/vunetenv/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:0:
      ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       #include <libpq-fe.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      
      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
      
      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for psycopg2 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running install
      /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg
      gcc -pthread -B /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include -I/home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/home/suneha/miniconda3/envs/vulogrca_core/include/python3.9 -I. -I/home/aayush/miniconda3/envs/vunetenv/include -I/home/aayush/miniconda3/envs/vunetenv/include/server -I/home/aayush/miniconda3/envs/vunetenv/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:0:
      ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       #include <libpq-fe.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      
      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
      
      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> psycopg2

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

**What I have already tried**

- I tried installing psycopg2-binary as suggested in the error description.
- I installed cmake  package based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470989/python-setup-py-bdist-wheel-did-not-run-successfully) and tried it again.

**My system**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.9.16

**Edit:**

The full text output I got when I executed `pip install psycopg2-binary` is as given below

```
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.6-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.0/3.0 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.9.6
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add full text output from `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: "Successfully installed"!