# Installing python package containing C code (pip install rvlib: bdist_wheel did not run successfully, -std=c99 ignored)

Tags: python, c, package, python-wheel

I am trying to install the Python package rvlib (in a virtual environment in PyCharm, although same error when using a basic cmd prompt). This is to install PySal if that changes anything.

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.10 (also tried on 3.8)

What I have tried:

- installing with conda (has been running unsuccessfully for hours)
- making sure C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x64 is in system path.
- above also performed directly in PyCharm
- adding CFLAG -std=99 to system variables
- installing Cmake
- installing in a brand new virtual environment
- installing latest version of wheel (already installed)
- Jeremy Thompson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470989/python-setup-py-bdist-wheel-did-not-run-successfully)
- clearing pip cache
- preemptively installing dependencies

These are the Visual Studio Build Tools I have installed:

- Code tools: Text Template Transformation
- Compilers, build tools and run times: 2022 Redistributable Update, C++ CMake tools for windows, MSVC v140 (Jeremy Thompson's solution attempt), MSVC v143, Windows Universal CRT SDK
- Debugging and Testing: all
- Development activities: C++ build tools core features, C++ core features, Windows 10 SDK (10.0.20348.0), Windows Universal C runtime

`pip install vlib`
[Full error text](https://pastebin.com/KvfGLbaX)

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion of the issue [here](https://github.com/pysal/pysal/issues/1267). "The root of the problem is that windows's default c-compiler (VSCode) does not support variable-length arrays (c99) mode."

All I personally managed to get working was working around the issue by installing subpackages individually.